# How to perform multi labeling classification (for CNN)?

Tags: deep-learning

I am currently looking into multi-labeling classification and I have some questions (and I couldn't find clear answers).

For the sake of clarity let's take an example : I want to classify images of vehicles (car, bus, truck, ...) and their make (Audi, Volkswagen, Ferrari, ...).

So I thought about training two independant CNN (one for the "type" classification and one fore the "make" classifiaction) but I thought it might be possible to train only one CNN on all the classes.

I read that people tend to use sigmoid function instead of softmax to do that. I understand that sigmoid does not sum up to 1 like softmax does but I dont understand in what doing that enables to do multi-labeling classification ?

My second question is : Is it possible to take into account that some classes are completly independant ?

Thridly, in term of performances (accuracy and time to give the classification for a new image), isn't training two independant better ?

Thank you for those who could give my some answers or some ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

Softmax is a special output function; it forces the output vector to have a single large value. Now, training neural networks works by calculating an output vector, comparing that to a target vector, and back-propagating the error. There's no reason to restrict your target vector to a single large value, and for multi-labeling you'd use a 1.0 target for *every* label that applies. But in that case, using a softmax for the output layer will cause unintended differences between output and target, differences that are then back-propagated.

For the second part: you define the target vectors; you can encode any sort of dependency you like there.

Finally, no - a combined network performs better than the two halves would do independently. You'd only run two networks in parallel when there's a difference in network layout, e.g. a regular NN and CNN in parallel might be viable.

Comment: First, thank you for you really complete answer @MSalters.
I just need one more precision : Will my network figure out by itself, during the training, that some classes are independant and some are not ? Or at least can I do something to help it understand it (by linking some neurons or not) ?